# Session variable in header element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a header element that gets populated with a selected date from a datebox calendar.

Problem is I also have an AJAX call to load the content and this takes 10-15 seconds to load. When I update the header tag with cal date to show selected date it appears fine - I have to stop the current AJAX call if its still running and re-call it with new date selected.

I have been using location.reload() which simply reloads the browser. this losses all code assigned header date, and also allows the AJAX call to load twice!

```
function reajax() {
    $('#roster h1 > span').text(sessionStorage.currentDate);
    location.reload();

$('#callback').append('<div id="progress">Loading....</div>'); 
doRoster("doRoster", localUser, localPwd, localCode, reloadToday);
};
```

AJAX REQUESTED:

```
 function doRoster(action, xuser, xpwd, xcode, xdate) {

 $.get('https://www.xdomain.net/servlet/ServletController?device=stdbrowser&action=Login',
function(data) {

  var jaction = "https://www.xdomain.net/servlet/ServletController";

  $.post(jaction, { device: "stdbrowser", action: "doLogin", j_username: xuser, j_password: xpwd, j_accessCode: xcode, j_host: jaction }, function(data) {


    var jsindex = data.indexOf('initMenu(');  
    var jsessionid = data.substring(jsindex + 10, jsindex + 48);
    var prefix = data.substring(jsindex + 43, jsindex + 48);
    var doAction = "https://" + prefix + ".xdomain.net/servlet/ServletController;jsessionid=" + jsessionid + "?action=" + action + "&date=" + xdate;

    sessionStorage.jsid = jsessionid;
    sessionStorage.jsid_prefix = prefix;

    callLogStatus(prefix, jsessionid);

    $.get(doAction, function(data) {

    var iDivFormat = formatRxxxx(data);

    $('#callback').append('<div class="divCal"></div>');
    $('#callback .divCal').html(iDivFormat);
    $('#progress').remove();
    $('#callback .divCal ul').hide(); 

    getRosterSearch();

    });
  });
});

  return 
};
```

Comment: Where is the ajax call?

Comment: the ajax call loads initially on page load and then is recalled with the `doRoster()` above. if the first load completes, there is no problem. I guess I'm looking for how to stop an function before it completes instead of reloading the browser...

Comment: Can you include the code with the ajax call please?

Comment: Included code above...

Answer (score 0):

You can abort ajax call by doing this:

```
var call = $.ajax({
    // some settings
});

call.abort();
```

By the way: if the server takes 10-15 seconds to load data, then you have a serious problem on the server side and consider either fixing the service or not using it at all.

Comment: its actually screen scraping and data/page is large. would the call.abort() work the same on a function()?

Comment: looks like I need to keep the `location.reload` and find a way to assign the session.date back to the h1, just not sure what fires first on a location.reload, should I re-assign date in the page init?

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep a variable with the latest request.  Then whenever you need to make a new request, abort the previous.  Something like this:

```
var lastRequest;

function doRoster(action, xuser, xpwd, xcode, xdate) {

    if(lastRequest) lastRequest.abort();

    lastRequest = $.get(/* ... */, function(data) {

        lastRequest = $.post(/* ... */, function(data) {

            lastRequest = $.get(/* ... */, function(data) {

            });
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? the abort needs to take place from outside the doRoster function. This function call is treated as one event. The only ajax call that takes a long time is the 3rd and final request.

Comment: I don't see why that would be true, but if you want, do the abort outside of the function.